# Spring batch can't find entity persisted while processing

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

In one of our spring batch jobs, we create additional entities (`CompanyProfile`) during processing and persist them to the DB (in a separate transaction). These entities are referenced by other entities (`Vacancy`), which will be persisted by the writer, but unfortunate the writer fails with this error:

```
   Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.company.CompanyProfile with id 1409881
```

The model is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Vacancy {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company", nullable = true)
    private CompanyProfile company;
...
}

@Entity
public class CompanyProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
...
}
```

In the processor we have this:

```
CompanyProfile company = companyProfileService.handleCompany(compName);
vacancy.setCompany(company);
```

Where the method `companyProfileService.handleCompany()` is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )`

I'm sure the `CompanyProfile` gets persisted - I can see it in the DB, but when the `Vacancy` gets saved by the `ItemWriter`, it fails with the above exception. (also, note that the id of the persisted entity is mention in the exception above)

Do you see any reason why the writer would fail in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With information you gave us my guess is that transaction opened by SB is unable to see data persisted by `companyProfileService.handleCompany()` method because service component uses a different transaction than SB ones; you have to check database `ISOLATION_LEVEL` property

Comment: many thanks - some how I was not thinking about the isolation level... solved it with 'READ_COMMITTED'